# Как обнаружить и удалить альтернативный поток NTFS из массива байт файла?

Tags: c#, файлы

Проблема вот в чем: я знаю как это сделать через WinAPI на Windows, но мне нужно провернуть ту же операцию в WebAPI под linux для файлов, загружаемых пользователем. Некоторые клиенты сервиса используют всяко-разную криптографию и системы защиты периметра под Windows, которые добавляют служебные данные в альтернативные потоки файлов. Содержимое альтернативного потока, каким-то образом, сохраняется в основном потоке при upload-е файла, что мешает нормальной работе с файлом на других клиентах, например, не проходит валидация подписи и прочие тараканы связанные с тем, что массив данных файла отличается от исходного.

Существует ли способ обнаружить и безболезненно удалить такие "лишние" данные в массиве байт, переданном при upload-е файла?

Comment: Скопируйте такой файл во временный каталог на файловой системе, не поддерживающей файловые потоки, а потом обратно. Делов-то...

Comment: @Akina т.е. простое сохранение файла в EXT3/4 на сервисе уберет всю эту муть? Просто у меня нет возможности повлиять на действия пользователя

Comment: Мне на винде помогла простая перезапись файла. Да, я не детектирую наличие потока, но тупо `File.WriteAllBytes(File.ReadAllBytes(...))` чистило поток.

Comment: *т.е. простое сохранение файла в EXT3/4 на сервисе уберет всю эту муть?* Если EXT3/4 не поддерживает потоки - да. Более того, можно просто загружать файлы прямо туда, проблема сдохнет не родившись.

Comment: @Akina ок, попробую, запросил проблемный файл для тестов, отпишусь по факту.

Comment: Чё запрашивать-то? любой файл на винде качни с Инета - эксплорер в поток пишет хрень, от которой выскакивает "Файл получен из хрен знает откуда...". Ну или у Руссиновича утиля есть для работы с потоками.

Comment: @Akina да вот с такими-то проблем почему-то не было. Не знаю с чем связано, вроде механизм один и тот-же используется, но в одном случае дополнительных действий не требуется, а в другом только ручное удаление левого потока решает проблему =(

Comment: А ОС какая там, куда файлы грузятся? а то загрузил, потом `streams.exe -d имя_файла.ext`, и нет потоков. И в никсах стопудово есть какая-нить тулза для удаления альтернативных потоков.

Comment: @Akina там где наблюдалась проблема WinServer + IIS и файлы там сразу в БД пишутся, сейчас переползаем в Alt с отказом от хранения файлов в БД. Но я уже проверил, да затирается. А при скачивании обратно приписывается уже другой. Похоже что только для Win проблема актуальна.